# Hack required to make undefined == true in eval

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a function that allows strings to be evaluated against an environment

```
function filt(M, filterString, cb){
    var res
    try{
        res = eval(filterString)
    } catch(me){
        // If in doubt permit               
        res = true
    }
    cb(res)
}
```

The problem is that I would like this filter to be optimistic. You can see the optimism in the `catch`, where the response is set to true if anything goes wrong.

If I run `filt({ age : 20 }, 'M.age < 21', callback)` then my callback returns `true`. Similarly `filt({ age: 21}, 'M.age < 21', callback)` returns false as expected.

I would however like the following to return true also:
`filt({}, 'M.age < 21', callback)`. However `undefined==true` is false (similar for all boolean expressions with `undefined`). I thought about inspecting the string using regular expression (all my variables are passed as fields on the object `M`). So that if `filterString` contains `M.varname` (or `M."varname"` or `M["varname"]` then replace with true if there is no such field on `M`. However prior to coding this I thought I would put the feelers out to see if there is a better approach.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Thanks to the feedback I can see that my entire approach needs rethinking. To simplify then I am wondering if there is a a method of evaluating expressions with unknown values so that if an expression involves and unknown then the outcome is unknown. For example in pseudocode:

```
M > 21 = unknown if M == unknown
M > 21 = true if M == 23
M > 21 = false if M == 'fish'
M > 21 | true = true independent of the value of M.
```

Comment: Could you pass 2 arguments in place of `filterString` as `field` (eg `age`) and `comparison` (eg. `"< 21"`)?

Comment: What are you using this for? I'm sure there's a better alternative than `eval` that doesn't need a `try/catch`.

Comment: Not really, I have greatly simplified the function for the sake of a minimal example. The object `M` is in reality going to have a lot of fields, possibly nested.

Comment: Ok, but the `field` could be `"outerObject.innerObject.someProperty"` and the `comprison` still `"<21"` - the point being if you can separate the "what field" from the "what boolean check` then you can first verify the propery (or nested property) is valid or not before doing the boolean check. Essentially - what im saying is that your title is a quintessential XY Problem. You dont want a hack to make `undefined == true` you want a better solution to your actual problem.

Comment: @Cerbrus I have a directed graph that as it is walked along gathers information that is stored on an object `M`. The nodes of the graph can be traversed if the information does not forbid it according to simple filter expressions. These filter strings need to be able to contain any other javascript `tolower`, `Math.random()` etc. What could I try instead of eval?

Comment: You are looking for ES6 Proxies. They are not very cross-browser, and node doesn't support them either. If your environment is Firefox (Spidermonkey) or Edge (Chakra), then it will work. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy

Comment: @Awal_Garg. Thanks for that - very interesting. Do you know of any libs for node that implement this?

Comment: @Joe It is an internally exposed construction, so libs can't help you here. It is *not possible* for a lib to implement proxies.

Comment: @Jamiec, but what if I have multiple comparisons. For example `filterString = '(M.age < 21 | !M.taken.atest ) & M.height < 3.1 | Math.random() < .5)'`

Comment: @Joe Yes. Node implements an old style Proxy that can be enabled with command line flag and [shimmed](https://github.com/Swatinem/proxy) to new standard Proxy.

Comment: @Sheepy, thanks - feel like I am stepping into deep water.

Comment: Why the downvote for the question? Is it off-topic or ill-defined somehow?

Comment: @Joe I can't say for others, but I am *tempted* to downvote for you are showing some very horrible code and asking for an even more horrible solution, on par with [parsing HTML with regx](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/893578) (if such horrors are comparable).

Comment: @Sheepy. Hmm fair enough I suppose, so a to steer others clear if this sort of problem is a minefield. Enabling harmony-proxies seems like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut so I think I am going to roll an expression parser. Never tried with JS only ANTLR in Java. I guess I was optimistic that I could just hack javascript to provide my DSL for filters. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I still don't see why you would use `eval` instead of simple functions. If you need multiple comparisons, just use multiple functions (a tree of simple functions). True, JS is still a bit chatty when using anonymous functions (unless you're running with ES6 and arrow functions), but it's quite simple to use.

Comment: @Luann The reason I am using eval is because the expression is stored as a string in a database. A string is my starting point.

Answer (score 0):

*Partial solution: Does not answer the question*

I post here a partial solution that is overly optimistic. This covers my unit tests but it is horrendous and probably dangerous. Please read the comments by other user above before even thinking about doing anything like this.

```
function(M, filterString, cb){

    var regexp = /M(\."\w+"|\.'\w+'|\.\w+|\["\w+"\]|\['\w+'\])+/g
    /*
        Matches all of the following 
        M."a"
        M.'a'
        M.a["b"].c
        M["a"].b['c']
        M.a.b
    */

    var expectedVariables = filterString.match(regexp)

    // Check that the variables in the filterString are available
    var allMetaDataAvailable = true
    for(var i=0 ; i< expectedVariables.length; i++){
        if (typeof eval(expectedVariables[i]) =='undefined'){
            allMetaDataAvailable = false
        }
    }

    if (!allMetaDataAvailable){
         // Optimistic
         cb(true)
    } else {
         // Evalue the expression
         var res
         try{
              res = eval(filterString)
         } catch(me){
              // something went wrong - allow.
              res = true
         }
         cb(res)

     }
}
```

The reason that this is only a partial solution is that a string expression `M.age < 20 | M.gender=='f'` will return true if `M = { gender : 'm' }`, because it does not know the value of `age` then it optimistically says that the expression may (in future - once the value is defined) become true - which in this case is clearly not possible because we already know that the value of `gender` is wrong.

**Update:** I have now discovered a very lightweight library called [JSEP.js](http://jsep.from.so/) for creating the abstract syntax tree of a javascript expression. This would seem an ideal starting point within which to implement a javascript based ternary logic capable of handling unknown values in boolean expressions correctly.